# Strange 403 error on trying to get metadata for Office 365 groups

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

We're trying to get Office 365 group metadata, by doing http request : 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/?$select=description,displayName,groupTypes,mail,mailEnabled,mailNickname,onPremisesLastSyncDateTime,onPremisesSecurityIdentifier,onPremisesSyncEnabled,proxyAddresses,securityEnabled,visibility,allowExternalSenders,autoSubscribeNewMembers,isSubscribedByMail,unseenCount

while on some customer accounts it's working fine, on another we're getting :
ERROR 403 - ErrorAccessDenied ,message:Unified groups aren't supported
where user credentials that used to call belongs to the group admin.

Any thoughts ?

Thanks

Comment: Check to see if there are any group creation policies in place that might be restricting this user's ability to work with groups.

Comment: Can it be in this case, where user is group owner?

Comment: Yes. They may be that group's owner, but not have permissions to create new groups.

Comment: But, in our case we're not trying to create groups, just trying to retrieve it metadata.

Comment: I understand, but the API request you are making is getting all groups. I reached out to our Groups team and they asked that we check this. Just trying to collect the requested information at this point :)

Comment: Well, seems in this case no creation policies was defined.

Comment: Interesting, if I remove from the request allowExternalSenders,autoSubscribeNewMembers,isSubscribedByMail it passes without any issue, MS guys , any comment on this ? Should you return permissions issue on 3 properties ? Is it related to the permissions or it's jus tnot correct error message ? And why it's failed , when I have those 3 properties in the request ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tested the http request listed above, and it appears including properties after "visibility" cause the request to fail. I think you may be hitting the maximum character limit that can be served in the OData request. Removing the additional parameters brings you below the character threshold, which might be why it succeeds.

Comment: Well, could be, but we found that removing listed above 3 properties solves as well, removing one didn't helped. And on some customers it's pass with those 3 and on another it's fails. So, it's very strange.

Comment: So, this request for example
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/.{guid}?$select=description,displayName,groupTypes,mail,mailEnabled,mailNickname,onPremisesLastSyncDateTime,onPremisesSecurityIdentifier,onPremisesSyncEnabled,proxyAddresses,securityEnabled,visibility,allowExternalSenders,autoSubscribeNewMembers,isSubscribedByMail,unseenCount has same size and works just fine on another groups.

Comment: After further research, I don't think it's related to character limit. It seems these 4 properties (allowExternalSenders, autoSubscribeNewMembers, isSubscribedByMail, and unseenCount) are not returned by default in the Get Group call. To retrieve them through a $select query, you'll need to pass the guid of the group for which you want to retrieve the properties. For example, this query would work successfully: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/02bd9fd6-8f93-4758-87c3-1fb73740a315?$select=allowExternalSenders,autoSubscribeNewMembers,isSubscribedByMail,unseenCount

Comment: Yes, I know this link, but this doesn't explains why for one groups this request works fine, while for another it's fails, with all those fields. So, and why error that returned related to permissions, with HTTP 403. So, there 2 issues : 1) Why it's works fine on some groups and fails on another. 2) Why such strange error ?

Comment: Mike, is there any news regarding this issue? I can provide problematic group id in mail (private) Thanks.